# jQuery regex not working

Tags: jquery, regex, textarea

I am trying to replace the text in textarea using jQuery regex. But it does not seem to work. http://regexr.com/38t41 says my regex is valid. But it does not seem to work. Here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8uzn2/9/

HTML:

```
<button id="updt">Update</button>
<div id="header-code-area" class="codearea">
  <textarea id="show_header" cols="88" rows="4">
    <!-- Paste this code to the header of your website -->
    <!--front--><link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allerta Stencil' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  </textarea>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#updt").click(function () {
        //replace in paragraph
        var match1 = /<\!--front--><link\shref='http:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com\/css\?family=[\w+ \w+]+/
        console.log(match1);
        //update textarea
        $("textarea#show_header").filter(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.html(function () {
                return $this.html().replace(match1, "<!--front--><link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=");
            });
        }); //end textarea
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `filter` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting value of the form elements you should use the `val` method.

```
$("#show_header").val(function (i, currentVal) {
    return currentVal.replace(match1, "<!--front--><link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, its working. But I don't understand why filter is working for other replacements but its not working here.